# What Magit command allows re-editing the todo list, during a rebase?

Tags: magit

Magit's `magit-interactive-rebase` function handles the Git interactive rebase very well.

But there's one action it seems to be missing. According to `git-rebase(1)`, the four actions during interactive rebase are `--continue`, `--skip`, `--abort`, `--edit-todo`.

That last one doesn't appear to be available in Magit. How can I tell Magit to:

- Present the rebase todo document again, for editing. Then
- Continue on, obeying the edited rebase todo document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*First update to `2.1.0` which was released a little while ago and brings many improvements in this area. Then...*

Rebase sequences are initiated and continued using the rebase popup on <kbd>r</kbd>. Depending on whether a sequence is already in progress or not, the popup offers different commands. When a rebase is in progress, then "edit" is one of these commands.

Comment: @bignose Does this work for you? If so, then please accept the answer.